# Creating clickable polygons three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using three.js for creating clickable polygons, when i create polygon in this way

```
var geo = new THREE.Geometry();
            geo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0.3, 0.3, 0.5));
            geo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0.3, 0.4, 0.5));
            geo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0.4, 0.4, 0.5));
            geo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0.6, 0.35, 0.5));
            geo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0.4, 0.3, 0.5));                

            for (var face = 0 ; face < 5 - 2; face++) {
                // this makes a triangle fan, from the first +Y point around
                geo.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, face + 1, face + 2));
            }

            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: Math.random() * 0xffffff, opacity: 0.5 }));
            geo.computeFaceNormals();

            layer.add(mesh);
            objects.push(mesh);
```

it displaying, but the polygon is not clickable.
If I cretae in this way

```
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(0.02, 0.02, 0.02);
            var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: Math.random() * 0xffffff, opacity: 0.5 }));

            object.position.x = 0.5;
            object.position.y = 0.5;
            object.position.z = 0.5;

            layer.add(object);
            objects.push(object);
```

everything is work fine and cube is clickable, but I need a polygon.
Click Event method

```
function onDocumentMouseClick(event) {
        layerMap.update();
        var vector = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
        var ray = projector.pickingRay(vector, camera);
        var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(objects);
        if (intersects.length > 0) {
            intersects[0].object.material.color.setHex(Math.random() * 0xffffff);
        }
    }
```

I have too much different polygons
How to create clickable polygon?

Comment: Are you using the current version of three.js r.60?

Comment: Yes, THREE.WebGLRenderer 60.

Comment: Can you provide a live example?

Comment: Don't you just need to compute the BoundingSPhere/BoundingBox for your custom geometry? using the respective functions?

Comment: I can provide only link to zip file [link] http://www.tempfiles.net/download/201309/319620/examples.html

Comment: Any of this method doesn't help. geo.computeFaceNormals();
geo.computeVertexNormals();
geo.computeBoundingSphere();
geo.computeBoundingBox();

Comment: Each object in the `intersects` array contains a `face` property (not just the `object` as you're currently using it) that should be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors.

Your `OrthographicCamera` constructor args are incorrect -- it is upside down, and the near plane is behind the camera.

```
//this.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(0, 1, 0, 1, -3000, 3000);
this.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3000);
```

The winding order on your geometry is clockwise; it should be counter-clockwise (CCW).

```
//geo.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, face + 1, face + 2));
geo.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, face + 2, face + 1));
```

Tip: debug with the non-minified version of three.js. Also, download a local copy for your use.

three.js r.60

Comment: This way help me to find interacting polygon, but I've got a new problem with zooming and dragging map, elements isn't fixed on the map, in my version zooming and dragging work as it should.

Comment: I answered your question about three.js. Please remember to "accept" this answer by clicking on the check mark. If you are having additional problems with your code, please post a new question. Try to ask questions that would be helpful to others. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `intersectTriangle()` function of the `THREE.Ray` class.
If `object` is your `THREE.Mesh` loop over your triangles and check for intersections like this:

```
function onDocumentMouseClick(event) 
{

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3((event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
    var ray = projector.pickingRay(vector, camera);
    var currentTriangle;
    var currentIntersection, chosenIntersection;
    var currentDistance, chosenDistance;
    var distanceVector;

    chosenIntersection = null;
    chosenDistance = Infinity;

    var vertices = object.geometry.vertices;

    for (var i = 0; i < object.geometry.faces.length; i++)
    {
      currentTriangle = object.geometry.faces[i];
      currentIntersection = ray.intersectTriangle( vertices[ currentTriangle.a ], vertices[ currentTriangle.b ], vertices[ currentTriangle.c ], true );

      if( currentIntersection !== null )
      {
        // The following code checks if a found intersection is closer to the camera than a previous one.
        distanceVector.subVectors(currentIntersection, ray.origin);
        currentDistance = distanceVector.length();

        if( currentDistance < chosenDistance)
        {
          chosenIntersection = currentIntersection;
          chosenDistance = currentDistance;
        }
      }   
   }
}
```